# Handle filename with spaces in system function

Tags: php

I have this code to detect the file charset.

```
$result = exec('file -i ' . $fromFile);
```

The result will be something like: "perk.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii"

All is well until $fromFile holds the filename which has spaces on it. Then it complains it could not read the file.

My first solution is to replace any space character with "\ ". But maybe there is a better way to solve this? I feel that I may miss something here.

Comment: Tried [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function to escape the filename.

Your code should be:

```
$result = exec('file -i ' . escapeshellarg($fromFile));
```